# Wordpress shows duplicated recent posts

Tags: wordpress, post

I am using underscores_me as the theme starter. I want to show the 3 most recent post, in my front page. But not as a sidebar, but as my main content. With the 200 text as an excerpt, ordered by date and in descending order.

I've been reading all over the net, I've been applying all the solutions that I could find, but all of them provide the 3 most recent posts, but it gets duplicated 10 times.

```
<ul>

<?php
$Poz = array(

    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
);

query_posts( $Poz );


while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?> yazısını oku."><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php  endwhile;  wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYiAq.jpg

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot, it looks like the entire `<ul>` is being duplicated - so the issue is not in the code above.

Something is looping through the code above 10 times - what file is this code in, and where is it being called from?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was editing content.php. Then I noticed that there was a loop in index.php as well. Thats why it was repeating. Thanks, now I got the solution.